# MySQL : Select from table based on shape of arabic character in a column

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, arabic

I have a table with arabic words, the column's collation is utf8_general_ci.
I want to retrieve words based on the shape of the arabic letter, not just the letter itself.

Ex : (ب) this is the base form of the letter. based on its place in a word it will have different shapes like (بـ) or (ـبـ) or (ـب)

First I tried to identify them in the column by using unicode
Ex :

(بـ) = 0xFE91 (unicode) = 0xEFBA91 (UTF-8)

using this query :

```
SELECT * FROM arabicwords WHERE ArWord = char(0xEFBA91 using utf8)
```

There are two issues here

First, I don't know how to use "LIKE" with the char() method. I tried to google it with no result.

Second, I tried using php to avoid the issue with LIKE.

```
$string ="U+FE91";
$utf8string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $string), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM arabicwords WHERE ArWord LIKE '%".$utf8string."%' ");
```

but this returns an empty result.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `... LIKE '%'+char(0xEFBA91 using utf8)+'%'`?

Comment: yes, and it produces an error

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
WHERE HEX(word) REGEXP '^(..)*EFBA91'
```

Explanation:

```
^  -- anchor at start of string
(..)*  -- any number of 2-byte pairs, namely hex pairs making up a character
EFBA91  -- match the hex for "beh initial form"
```

If, by "initial", this would be only at the start of the 'word', then this would work, and be more efficient:

```
WHERE HEX(word) LIKE 'EFBA91%'
```

This is probably much more efficient, assuming it works as I expect:

```
WHERE word LIKE UNHEX('EFBA9125')
```

(Note:  HEX('%') = '25'.)

(From OP's Comment:)

Should match:

```
مسابح  -- D985 D8B3 D8A7 D8A8 D8AD 
ابريق  -- D8A7 D8A8 D8B1 D98A D982
برق    -- D8A8 D8B1 D982
باسم   -- D8A8 D8A7 D8B3 D985
```

Should not match:

```
طبيب   -- D8B7 D8A8 D98A D8A8
كلب    -- D983 D984 D8A8
أب     -- D8A3 D8A8
مسبح   -- D985 D8B3 D8A8 D8AD
```

Since the hex is radically different, we need to depend on the `COLLATION` to recognize certain BEHs as matching the "initial form BEH".  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` implements the Unicode version 5.20 standard.  Perhaps someone else can decipher the standard enough to say how 5.20 handles this case.

Note that MySQL 8.0 has Unicode 9.0 with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.  It may be interesting to see if that works differently.

A test to see if two different Behs are treated equal:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
SELECT UNHEX('D8A8') = UNHEX('EFBA91');   -- returns 0 (false)
```

So, none of those words will match.  Similarly with version 8.0.15:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
SELECT UNHEX('D8A8') = UNHEX('EFBA91');    -- also false
```

If you want to discuss checking for `D8A8` at the start of a word, we can pursue that.

Comment: This returns the records where I put a single letter for testing. I used this website : [link](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=FE91&mode=hex)

But it doesn't return the records where there's a full word.

Only if I use the hex code of the general form of the letter does it return those records. But this isn't what I want since it return the word containing the letter with any shape.

Comment: @AbedAlRahmanMez - Please provide a short list of "words" that _should_ match, and a short list of words that should _not_match.  Be sure to include enough examples to cover your concerns about "full word", "general form", and "any shape".  (Sorry, I am only vaguely aware of the complexities of constructing Arabic words.  But I think I can work from examples.)

Comment: List of words that should match the search for (بـ) (0xEFBA91) : 
باسم, 
برق, 
ابريق, 
مسابح, 

List of words that shouldn't match : 
مسبح, 
أب, 
كلب, 
طبيب, 
An Arabic letter has four shapes (separate, beginning, middle, end)
These shapes are not much related to it's position in a word as much as what the letters are before and after, since there are letters that don't connect with the ones after them. for example (بـ) is the beginning shape of the letter (ب). in the word (ابريق) it is in its beginning form because the first letter (ا) doesn't connect with letters after it.

Comment: I see BEH (D8A8) in each word, but an explicit BEH INITIAL FORM (EFBA91) in any.  Hence, my REGEXP technique will not apply.

Comment: @AbedAlRahmanMezian - But...  `select "مسبح, أب, كلب, طبيب" LIKE '%ﺑ%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;` comes back with `1` (true).  (I have checked each word separately.)  Does this seem like a valid, but failing, "shouldn't match" test case?

Comment: Yes the letter (ب) in these words has the hex code of the general form of the letter, even though it has a different shape in each word.

Comment: And that select statement shouldn't return true, because none of the words have the the letter (ب) in it's  beginning form

Comment: @AbedAlRahmanMezian - However, there are multiple forms of "Beh".  And a collation _may_ treat them as equal.  In English, `B` and `b` are treated as equal by most collations.  (I don't know the Unicode rules on Beh, nor do I know where to find them.)

Comment: I see lots of BEH variants:  `ب,ٮ,ݐ,ݑ,ݒ,ݓ,ݔ,ݕ,ݖ,ﰅ,ﰆ,ﰇ,ﰈ,ﰉ,ﰊ,ﱪ,ﱫ,ﱬ,ﱭ,ﱮ,ﱯ,ﲜ,ﲝ,ﲞ,ﲟ,ﲠ,ﳡ,ﳢ,ﶞ,ﷂ,ﺏ,ﺐ,ﺑ,ﺒ`

Comment: I think that's the problem here, all forms of the letter are having the hex code for the general form of the letter. But what I can't understand is how it is able to still show the right form of the letter in the word.

Comment: I tried different collations and they all give the letter the same code no matter its form

Comment: @AbedAlRahmanMezian - a `CHARACTER SET` controls the encoding (hex); a `COLLATION` controls comparisons.  The only viable charsets are utf8 and utf8mb4.  There are many collations, but none seem to tackle Arabic.  You could file a feature request at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @AbedAlRahmanMezian - As for why the 'right form' is rendered...  There is a separate step in displaying thing -- the 'rendering' by the browser (or whatever output device).  I suspect it is looking at the context to decide how to draw each character.

Comment: oh okay, looks like a dead end then. thanks for the help